# How can I hide excel file column when doing import function?

Tags: laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I want to hide program_code column in excel file when importing. What should I do? I'm using ToModel for Class Import.

[image]

**ProgramImport.php**

```
public function __construct(string $program_code)
{
    $this->program_code = $program_code;
}

public function model(array $row)
{
    $row['program_code'] = $this->program_code;

    return new ProgramDetail([
        'program_detail_no' => $row['number'],
        'program_detail_code' => $row['program_code'],
        'program_detail_subject' => $row['subject_code'],
        'program_detail_semester' => $row['semester'],
        'program_detail_note' => $row['note'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by hide it? hide it from what?

Comment: I just updated the post. I want to not need to enter data for `program_code` column and how to hide `'program_detail_code'=>$row['program_code']`?

Comment: remove that line then .... not sure what the issue is here

Comment: so how can i assign default value to `program_code`...?

Comment: you mean to `program_detail_code`? ... you are the one doing the assignment in the code, assign what ever value you want, or do it at the database level ... still not sure what the problem is here

Comment: awesome, you should answer your question with your solution then

Answer (score 0):

you can for send a sub query to excel class. you are using which version of excel package?